# How to find Javascript which update matrix3d parameter?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

Checking this site: http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/chat/

[image]

Those small images in the patch bounching horizontally. I would see the parameters, how much is the maximum left right limit in the bounce. I would see the Javascript which moves the images. I think this is not a css / `@keyframes` animation, but Javascript / jQuery does it. But I do not know how to identify the script which works the indicated html elements.

Selected `rs-loop-wrap` has no `animation` attribute. Nor its parent elements.

What is the right way to get the background logic which is responsable for the animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this site is powered by the framework for wordpress
http://wordpress.framework-y.com/

This slider is used there 
https://www.sliderrevolution.com/examples/

This is a pretty flexible slider with a lot of settings, so looking for this specific code would be a very thankless task. I looked at one of the pictures and saw that it moved from -15px to 15px. Perhaps others are slightly larger or smaller. You should follow them in the developer panel:
[Dev Tools Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22mbW.jpg)
If you still want to look inside this slider, take a look at these files:

[Dev Tools Network tab Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbG72.jpg)

Have luck!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).